# Upgrading from 2.5.5 to 2.8 with tons of embeds and reverse related entries?

Tags: upgrade, embeds

I am working on a site using 2.5.5 and it uses embeds and related entries quite heavily. The embeds are used to hand parsing data the way the site requires it.

q1 Should I upgrade straight to 2.8 or do it in stages? (if so what)

q2 Does the updgrade change my templates and DB to support the new way embeds and related entries may be handled? 
Will it break them?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: Backup - files and database.

Seriously, get that site under source control. If anything goes wrong it's easier to roll back.

I'd just go straight to 2.8 -- I did one the other day going from 2.1.3 to 2.8 - if you run into issues then go for 2.7.x

It shouldn't break them if you're using recommended ways of embeds and related entries.